# Using the array_unique() function to remove the duplicated MYSQLI records without relying on SQL to do that

Tags: php

I know this is a strange question but I need to do this for personal reasons so I converted MYSQLI records into an array but I want to use PHP array_unique() function on the array that contains the MYSQLI

records to remove any duplicated values in that array without relying on any SQL commands to remove the duplicated records.

I tried many times on how I can do this and I failed many times. The code example below has no errors because I removed my failed attempts.

This is my code

```
<?php

$db_servername_1='localhost';
$db_username_1= 'jd';
$db_password_1= '1234';
$db_name_1= 'test';

$db_connect_1= new mysqli($db_servername_1,$db_username_1,$db_password_1,$db_name_1);

$db_query_1= "SELECT*FROM records ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";

$db_result_1= $db_connect_1->query($db_query_1);

while($db_row_1= $db_result_1->fetch_assoc()){
    $items[] = $db_row_1;
}

$items = array_reverse($items ,true);

foreach($items as $item){ ?>

<h1><?php echo $item['id']; ?></h1> 

<?php 

} 

?>
```

and this is the output 101,102,103,103.

if I find a way on how I can do this then the array output will look like this
instead 101,102,103 so how can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain why `$items = array_unique($items);` doesn't work? That would help answer your question.

Comment: Sadly I already tried that @Nick. It does not work if I do this $items = array_unique($items); it gives me this error "Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\path\example.php it is referring to your advice .

Comment: `foreach(array_unique(array_column($items, 'id')) as $k=>$id) { echo $id; echo $items[$k]['other_field']; }`

Comment: You already had asked that question (and probably deleted). If none of the answers work you should be more clear providing more information about what the array actually contains. `var_export($items)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_column` in conjunction with `array_unique` to get unique IDs.

```
$items =
[
  ['id' =>  1, 'text' => 'foo'],
  ['id' => 10, 'text' => 'bar'],
  ['id' => 10, 'text' => 'bar2'],
  ['id' =>  3, 'text' => 'baz'],
];

foreach(array_unique(array_column($items, 'id')) as $k=>$id)
  echo $id, ' => ', $items[$k]['text'], PHP_EOL
;
```

**output**

```
1 => foo
10 => bar
3 => baz
```

Comment: OMG thank you very much your advice solved my problem. I really appreciate that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two options for you here.

First, if what you've shown is all you're doing with the `$items` array, then only store the IDs in there, and then `array_unique` will work for you:

```
while($db_row_1= $db_result_1->fetch_assoc()){
    $items[] = $db_row_1['id'];
}

$items = array_reverse(array_unique($items));
```

If you go on to do other things with the `$items`, then only put unique items into that array:

```
while($db_row_1= $db_result_1->fetch_assoc()){
    if (!array_key_exists($db_row_1['id'], $items)) {
        $items[$db_row_1['id']] = $db_row_1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$query = "your query here";
$resultset = $db_connect_1->query($query);
$data_array = array();
while($current = $resultset->fetch_array()){
  array_push($data_array, $current['id']);
}

$non_duplicates_array = array_unique($data_array);
foreach ($non_duplicates_array as $current_id) {
  echo $current_id;
}
```